# How can I merge .m4v files?

Tags: macos, video

I transcoded a DVD into several `m4v` files with [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/). How can I merge these files into one `m4v` movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in iMovie app to do this.

Create a new project, add your video files, and drag them to the timeline in order. Export your project as an M4V (Share-> Export Movie).

If you're completely new to iMovie, some good introductory tutorials can be found on YouTube.

Comment: Why do you say "built-in"?

Comment: @GEdgar because iMovie comes with Mac OS X. It's 'built-in' to the system. You're right, it probably isn't the best choice of words, but it is true.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is almost correct. iMovie cannot handle M4Vs. So you have to go back to HandBrake and output the movies in MP4 format. At that point, you can use iMovie to stitch them together

Comment: @Julien iMovie can handle anything that QuickTime can, including M4V videos. Unless you're using some strange codec, you should be able to use them...

Comment: I tried importing m4v movies but find the two I want grayed out. A third one is selectable. All movie files were created by Handbrake and all are m4v. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Join can use MP4Box.

On the shell:

```
MP4Box $(for file in single*m4v; do echo -cat $file; done) joined.m4v
```

Related: https://superuser.com/a/364159/95878

Answer (score 0):

With iMovie (Yosemite) I merged 3 videos made on my iPhone 6s, piece of cake.

in Projects (tab) click +

Select Movie, no theme

Import Media (I had my 3 videos on desktop, Cmd-Click selected all 3 at same time)

Import Selected (presto, imported)

Click on one of the videos then Cmd-a for selecting all 3.

Click Hold-Drag all 3 down to timeline.

File, Share

If you click on Share, Email you will get 5 choices of sizes to save the video, it will then open an email and place the video in the email. You can drag the video off the email to desktop (or not) and delete the email.

There is a checkbox to add the video to Theater, where all your completed videos are shown.